# livequery not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, events, livequery

```
$('.DrpDwn option').livequery(function () {
            $(this).each(function () {
                $(this).addClass("DrpDwnItm");
            });
        });
$(function () {
        // updates Contract Id dropdown upon selection
        $(".DrpDwnItm").live('mouseover', function () {
            alert("text");
        });
    });
```

I've tried:

```
$(function () {
        // updates Contract Id dropdown upon selection
        $(".DrpDwnItm").live('hover', function () {
            alert("text");
        });
    });
```

This is working fine in FireFox. but does not work IE8. I'm trying to add a class to each option tag where the select tag has a class named DrpDwn. Can anyone provide any ideas has to why? Thanks

HTML MarkUp.

```
    <table id="wrkshtpar" >
<tr>
        <th colspan="3">REMAINING STOCKPILE
        </th>
</tr>
<tr>
        <th>
            Qty
        </th>
        <th>
            Rem %
        </th>
        <th>
            StkPl %
        </th>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td class="hidden">
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_0__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__SeqID" name="WorkSheetDetails[0].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].SeqID" type="hidden" value="3" />
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_0__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__ComponetLabel" name="WorkSheetDetails[0].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].ComponetLabel" type="hidden" value="REMAINING STOCKPILE" />
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_0__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__ComponetId" name="WorkSheetDetails[0].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].ComponetId" type="hidden" value="0" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="WorkSheetDetails_0__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__PartialQty">0</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_0__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__RemainingPercentage" name="WorkSheetDetails[0].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].RemainingPercentage" type="hidden" value="0.50" />
            <label for="WorkSheetDetails_0__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__RemainingPercentage">50.00 %</label>
        </td>
        <td>
                <input id="WorkSheetDetails_0__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__StkPileSeqId" name="WorkSheetDetails[0].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].StkPileSeqId" type="hidden" value="1" />

        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td class="hidden">
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_1__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__SeqID" name="WorkSheetDetails[1].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].SeqID" type="hidden" value="4" />
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_1__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__ComponetLabel" name="WorkSheetDetails[1].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].ComponetLabel" type="hidden" value="REMAINING STOCKPILE" />
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_1__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__ComponetId" name="WorkSheetDetails[1].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].ComponetId" type="hidden" value="0" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_1__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__PartialQty" name="WorkSheetDetails[1].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].PartialQty" size="5" type="text" value="400" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_1__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__RemainingPercentage" name="WorkSheetDetails[1].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].RemainingPercentage" type="hidden" value="0.50" />
            <label for="WorkSheetDetails_1__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__RemainingPercentage">50.00 %</label>
        </td>
        <td>
<select class="DrpDwn" id="WorkSheetDetails_1__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__StkPileSeqId" name="WorkSheetDetails[1].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].StkPileSeqId"><option selected="selected" value="1">50.00 %</option>
<option value="-1">100.00 %</option>
</select>                                </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hidden">
    <input id="WorkSheetDetails_2__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__SeqID" name="WorkSheetDetails[2].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].SeqID" type="hidden" value="5" />
    <input id="WorkSheetDetails_2__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__ComponetLabel" name="WorkSheetDetails[2].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].ComponetLabel" type="hidden" value="REMAINING STOCKPILE" />
    <input id="WorkSheetDetails_2__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__ComponetId" name="WorkSheetDetails[2].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].ComponetId" type="hidden" value="0" />
</td>
<td>
    <input id="WorkSheetDetails_2__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__PartialQty" name="WorkSheetDetails[2].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].PartialQty" size="5" type="text" value="100" />
</td>
<td>
    <input id="WorkSheetDetails_2__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__RemainingPercentage" name="WorkSheetDetails[2].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].RemainingPercentage" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <label for="WorkSheetDetails_2__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__RemainingPercentage">100.00 %</label>
</td>
<td>
<select class="DrpDwn" id="WorkSheetDetails_2__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__StkPileSeqId" name="WorkSheetDetails[2].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].StkPileSeqId"><option value="1">50.00 %</option>
<option selected="selected" value="-1">100.00 %</option>
</select>                                </td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td class="hidden">
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_3__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__SeqID" name="WorkSheetDetails[3].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].SeqID" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_3__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__ComponetLabel" name="WorkSheetDetails[3].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].ComponetLabel" type="hidden" value="REMAINING STOCKPILE" />
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_3__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__ComponetId" name="WorkSheetDetails[3].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].ComponetId" type="hidden" value="0" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_3__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__PartialQty" name="WorkSheetDetails[3].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].PartialQty" size="5" type="text" value="0" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="WorkSheetDetails_3__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__RemainingPercentage" name="WorkSheetDetails[3].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].RemainingPercentage" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <label for="WorkSheetDetails_3__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__RemainingPercentage">0.00 %</label>
        </td>
        <td>
<select class="DrpDwn" id="WorkSheetDetails_3__MyWorkSheetPartials_0__StkPileSeqId" name="WorkSheetDetails[3].MyWorkSheetPartials[0].StkPileSeqId"><option value="1">50.00 %</option>
<option value="-1">100.00 %</option>
</select>                                </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I thought that `livequery` was replaced by `live` when it was integrated into jQuery directly.

Comment: Can you provide us with the HTML you're using?

Comment: I know parts of livequery were integrated into JQuery but not all. at least that's what I found on several other post I've read.

Comment: Note: you don't need to wrap .live() calls in a doc ready e.g. - $(function(){ });.  http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/